# What is the correct English word for this piece of paper around these notebooks?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to know the precise English word for the paper wrapped around these notebooks.

[image: strip of paper wrapped around three notebooks]

Comment: Just a warning, i have read the answers, and I wouldn't know what they were talking about if I had read any of them, before today.

Comment: On a hunch, I did a search on "paper strap", and saw an advertisement for "bill straps" to bind currency banknotes together in a similar way.

Comment: There very likely isn't a precise English word for this particular thing.

Comment: There are _several_ precise words for this thing, @N.Virgo. Which one you choose is probably going to be determined by what particular industry you work in and what others in that industry call said "little paper band thing".

Comment: There's a difference between ''there is not a word for X'' and ''there is a word but most native speakers don't know it''.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is a ***bellyband***:

> a band of paper around a new book, usually printed with information about the book's contents and sometimes used instead of a book jacket.

([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bellyband))

> a band that is used as packaging or decoration around a book, magazine, or similar item.

([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bellyband))

[image] ([rhollick.wordpress.com](https://rhollick.wordpress.com/2018/08/06/belly-band/))

[image] ([www.pinterest.it](https://www.pinterest.it/pin/449374869063491247/))

Comment: Are you sure? The OP's picture is not of a book, but of three notebooks; blank notebooks that can be written in. The band of paper around those three notebooks is used to bind them together in a packaging that makes it clear it's a set of three. That looks very different from the belly band used in libraries for newly-published books and it probably doesn't have the same name.

Comment: @Stef - yes, bellyband applies to the OP pictures as well. As you can see from the description the band is..”usually printed with information about the book's contents”. The band provides information of what is inside, be it a book or a memo book.

Comment: [Oxford Languages Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=bellyband+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=bellyband+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i10i512j0i390l2.7612j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  gives a broader definition: **bellyband**: a band wrapped around an item of merchandise, especially a book or magazine.

Comment: No law against using two references. A single dictionary may be incomplete / out-of-date / over-tolerant / noncomprehensive .... You can be almost certain that OL have justification for their choice of 'item of merchandise, especially ...' here.

Comment: I am absolutely persuaded by the references cited this is the right answer, but as a native speaker who still reads paper books a fair bit, I did not know this word before today. Unless speaking to someone who works in the publishing industry, it may be helpful to provide abundant context or even a full definition before using this word if you want to be understood.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman - I think  belly is the  relevant term here. Unlike other more general and more intuitive expressions such as, paper bands, paper strips, etc. bellyband refers to the specific position in which the band is generally placed, that is in the lower part (the belly) of the book, magazine, etc. so as not to hide the central part of the cover where usually most important information are (title, sub title, author etc.).

Comment: The term is clearly trade jargon - there are lots of words like this that are known to people who work in a particular field, but unfamiliar to the general public (who are unlikely to need a word for the thing). The question asked for the correct word, not for a word that's known to the general populace.

Answer (score 12):

## sleeve

Apart from the formal / technical answers already posted, in everyday conversation (England, UK) I'd simply refer to it as a **sleeve** (or a cardboard sleeve).

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sleeve

> a cover to protect something:
>
> Can you put the record back in its sleeve, please?

or

> a *tube-shaped* covering

(The dictionary definition says "to protect a part of a machine", but common usage would be a lot more general than that)

If you do an image search for "cardboard sleeve" in your favourite search engine you'll find a fair number of similar examples...

Comment: A sleeve is normally intended for protection, as the Cambridge definition you quote says - records most notably, but also DVDs, video games, knives, etc. This little strip doesn't protect anything. It's not a bad suggestion, but there seem to be more exact alternatives.

Comment: @StuartF - The other answers are definitely more precise (which the OP asked for, tbf), but they sounds more like technical terms used in the packaging industry rather than general day-to-day use - I've never heard them before. Depends on what the OP wants I guess - doesn't hurt to have another option :-)...

Comment: @StuartF sometimes the exact word isn't actually useful for a general audience

Answer (score 11):

## *wrap-around band*

> A paper strip wrapped around a book like a dust jacket, but smaller in height than the book. It is typically used for promotional purposes and may be added post-publication .**..

From:  wrap-around band  in  The Oxford Companion to the Book

Subjects: Literature — Bibliography

[The Oxford Companion to the Book](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803124925668;jsessionid=D051FA2D04E0E9F3A1A45AA5E93A4123)

The same would go for the notebooks in the question.

## *paper bands*

Or, less fancy, just *paper bands*:

[extrapackaging.com/bands](https://www.extrapackaging.com/bands/index.htm)

[image: extrapackaging.com]

Answer (score 7):

I would have called this an ***obi*** (on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obi) as “A strip of paper looped around a book or other product”). But this is possibly just jargon relating to the paper strips included with CDs and games imported from Japan where the word originates.

Comment: An obi is a Japanese sash for traditional dress.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obi_(publishing)) says that it is an Obi, and then adds that "In English, the term belly-band is sometimes used instead".

Comment: @Lambie It can be.  It is also the buckle-less belt used in the gi of various traditional Japanese martial arts.

Answer (score 4):

> **wrapper**  noun the cover,
> 1)usually of paper or cellophane, in
> which something is wrapped
> 2)a dust jacket of a book

[dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wrapper)

Just because the wrapper has got very small and less wasteful, that is what it is, the wrapper holding 3 books together.

And in a sentence

> Just take that little wrapper off the books so we can get started.

Comment: Do you mean "take that little wrapper off (of) the books"?

Comment: @Brandin most likely

Comment: Candy wrapper. Here, they seem to mean the dust jacket....